# How to use Maven to Create JSP + Servlet + TOMCAT + MySQL

Tags: maven, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using intellij.

The way I am creating project is "File -> New -> Project -> JavaEnterprise -> Web Application (Select Server)"

I want to know how to set it up with Maven.

I need JSP, Servlet, TOMCA, MySQL

Comment: if you tell me what is wrong with my question, I can change it. Why are you down-voting without comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In intelliJ, select maven from new project. Then check, "create from archetype". Select "archetype-maven-webapp"

After the project is created, add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.38</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

in the pom file.
Wait till it loads. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, this is what I was asking for.

Comment: You can use the command line ``mvn archetype:generate``. This is normally designed to create a new project from an archetype, but it will list availables archetypes if you do not specify one.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about [maven archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

Comment: can you please give me a sample of required archetypes.

Comment: You can use the command line ``mvn archetype:generate``. This is normally used to create a new project from an archetype, but it will list availables archetypes if you do not specify one. Please note that i'm not sure you will find a "servlet+tomcat+mysql" archetype, i think the "archetype-maven-webapp" archetype will be ok for start

Answer (score 0):

Maven has concept of [archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

From the list of available archetypes you could potentially use `spring-boot-sample-web-jsp-archetype`. It will create Spring Boot application (by default based on Tomcat). It should also suit for development of servlets.

Unfortunately concerning MySQL dependency you need to provide it manually or check what is generated by other archetypes.