# Tomcat does not find JDBC Driver after importing via Maven

Tags: java, maven, jsp, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm new to JSP, so I'm playing around with it a bit. I've created a Maven project in Intellij and imported the dependencies that I need in my `pom.xml`, namely `mysql-connector` and `servlet-api`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.20</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have a JSP file that accesses the local MySQL database using the corresponding Driver.

```
<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/DemoJSP";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
%>
```

However, when I run the Tomcat server, I get `HTTP Status 500`. The cause of this is the line `Class.forName("...")`, so the thrown exception is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. I have tried thousands of Maven reimports, but nothing helps. Is there anything that I'm missing?

**P.S.:** similar questions like [How to use Maven to Create JSP + Servlet + TOMCAT + MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040861/how-to-use-maven-to-create-jsp-servlet-tomcat-mysql) or [Where do I have to place the JDBC driver for Tomcat's connection pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161747/where-do-i-have-to-place-the-jdbc-driver-for-tomcats-connection-pool/13175611#13175611) do not solve my problem.

Comment: What's in your webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory? Do you see the MySQL driver there?

Comment: @dnault if I add the MySQL driver there, the URL won't open at all. And I get this `org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.` Eventually Intellij says that the specified URL could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in url for **localhost** port **3306** not 80.

And if you get an error whit time zone, use this string :

---

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DemoJSP";
String timezone = "?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
String username = "root";
String password = "";
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + timezone, username, password);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe the port number was the problem. I changed it to **3306** and it worked! Thanks a lot, I've been struggling with this error the whole day..

Comment: your database use the port 3306 for localhost

Comment: This can't have been the solution to the problem, because changing this won't fix the `ClassNotFoundException` that the OP reported.

Comment: Yes, and I'm saying that that change can't fix the `ClassNotFoundException`, so the OP had a different problem than described in the question, or did something else as well that fixed the `ClassNotFoundException`, and this fixes the next problem they were confronted by.